# React Native Custom TextInput object losing focus after each character

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am having an issue with the TextInput losing focus after a character is typed. It is only happening in my custom TextInput object. After each character is typed the keyboard is dismissed and I have to reselect the object to get the keyboard back.

I have only run this code on an Android phone. I am not sure how iOS works.

I have looked through many threads on this site and others and I can't find anything that works to keep the focus.

In the following code, I have included 2 TextInput objects. One is my custom object, MyTextInput. The other is the generic TextInput object. When text is entered in the generic one focus is not lost and the keyboard is not dismissed. In the custom, one focus is lost and the keyboard goes away.

Any help would be appreaciated.

```js
import React, { Component , useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,

} from 'react-native';

const Form = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: "", a: ""});

    const MyTextInput = ({ valueVar, name, type, onChange }) => {
       return (
            <TextInput

                style={styles.textInputStyle}
                value={valueVar}
                onChangeText={text => onChange({ name, type, text })}
            />
       );
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, type, text} = event;
        setValues({...values, [name]: text})
    }


    const handleChangeTI = (text) => {
        setValues({...values, a: text})
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>email </Text>
                <MyTextInput
                    name="email"
                    type="text"
                    valueVar={values.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                </MyTextInput>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>TextInput</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInputStyle}
                    value={values.a}
                    onChangeText={handleChangeTI}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );      // return
};      //  const

export default Form;

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    containerStyle:
    {
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    textStyle:
    {
        color: 'green',
        height: 30,
        width: 200,
        fontSize: 18,
    },
    textInputStyle:
    {
        color: 'black',
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        textDecorationLine: 'none',
        fontSize: 15,

    },
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MyTextInput` components are being recreated and re-rendered each time you type something. Move the function into a new file or outside of your `Form` component.

```js
import React, { Component , useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';


const MyTextInput = ({ valueVar, name, type, onChange }) => {
   return (
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInputStyle}
            value={valueVar}
            onChangeText={text => onChange({ name, type, text })}
        />
   );
};

const Form = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({ email: "", a: ""});

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, type, text} = event;
        setValues({...values, [name]: text})
    }

    const handleChangeTI = (text) => {
        setValues({...values, a: text})
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>email </Text>
                <MyTextInput
                    name="email"
                    type="text"
                    valueVar={values.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                </MyTextInput>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>TextInput</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInputStyle}
                    value={values.a}
                    onChangeText={handleChangeTI}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );      // return
};      //  const

export default Form;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle:
    {
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    textStyle:
    {
        color: 'green',
        height: 30,
        width: 200,
        fontSize: 18,
    },
    textInputStyle:
    {
        color: 'black',
        height: 40,
        width: 200,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        textDecorationLine: 'none',
        fontSize: 15,

    },
});
```